# Ember.js. Is it possible to replace index.html by index.jsp(for example)

Tags: ember.js

I want to use EmberJS insuide java web-application. And I want to use it inside JSP page. Can I configure ember compiler to use index.jsp instead of index.html?

And can I use live update without ember server to compile Ember App in different output directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addon may help you do what you're after: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-index

In general though, the recommendation would be to use a strategy like the one known as Lightning Deploys (see http://www.ember-CLI-deploy.com for more details). What you would do is read the Ember index.html file in from somewhere using your index.jsp file.